# Deselect/Select all checkboxes in Class for D3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

```
function deselectAll(){
d3.selectAll('input').property('checked', false);
drawUpdate();
}
```

I'm trying to deselect all checkboxes listed under a certain class because I have two seperate classes for two sets of checkboxes. Is it possible to do that with D3? I tried replacing 'input' with '.checkboxClass'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can do that:

```
d3.selectAll('.someclass').property('checked', false);
```

Test it here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/risto/28qwzwsr/)

What is the problem, when you try to select the checkboxes by their class?

Comment: thanks! I think I did the same thing, but I dumbed out an used the class that contains all the boxes instead of having classes set for each individual box

Answer (score 0):

If you want to uncheck checkbox, then use:

```
d3.selectAll('input').trigger('click')
```

Comment: If the box is not checked, this will check the box. So one would need to check whether it's checked before ...